# git: get the list of files that have been modified along one specific file

Tags: git, git-log

I'd like to check which files have been modified at the same time as one specific file. Specifically, I want to get the history of this specific file, and for each commit of this history I want to know which files were affected.

When I do `git log --name-only`, I get the full history of commits, as well as a list of files that have been modified, for each commit.

Now if I do `git log <file>`, I get the history of the commits that involved this specific file.

`git log --name-only <file>`, however, do not include the full list of files modified by each commits. Instead it only shows me `<file>`, which is quite useless to be honest.
Is there any way to make this command include all files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipeline the two commands.

```
$ git log --format="%h" <file-name> | xargs git show --name-only
```

Here:

**git log --format="%h"** : select the commit-sha where the given file is changed

**xargs git show --name-only**: takes the selected commits as args and show the full changed file names.

Comment: Adding [`--follow`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---follow) to `git log` is also useful, so file renames are followed where possible.

Answer (score 5):

Use `git-rev-list` to list commits affecting specific path and then `git-show` to get all the files modified in each commit:

`git show --name-only $(git rev-list HEAD -- PATH)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also Use [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/download/) tool (UI based tool for Git, similar to TortoiseSVN) for the same.

After Installing TortoiseGit-

1. Right Click on the file and Go to TortoiseGit in menu.
2. Click on **Show log**.

It will show the Commit history of that file along with other files which are included with those commits. It will also show the changes in the files.